# Firebase SimpleLogin facebook auth gives error when used on ie10 on windows phone

Tags: firebase

this is my first question on SO, so I hope I will formulate it well.

Simply put, I have a firebase-hosted app reachable at http://campanelly.firebaseapp.com

It is still in development stage, so it does not work completely. What does work on most browser EXCEPT IE10 on windows phone is the facebook login. The facebook popup correctly show up, I put username and password, the popup closes, but the `FirebaseSimpleLogin` object returns an error in the auth callback. I inspected the object with dev tools and it's an unknown error. this is the stacktrace:

```
Error: FirebaseSimpleLogin: An unknown error occurred.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fb.simplelogin.Errors.format (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.3.2/firebase-simple-login.js:33:294)
    at Object.fb.simplelogin.Errors.get (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.3.2/firebase-simple-login.js:33:429)
    at fb.simplelogin.transports.XHR_.formatError_ (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.3.2/firebase-simple-login.js:94:317)
    at XMLHttpRequest.fb.simplelogin.transports.XHR_.open.f.onreadystatechange (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.3.2/firebase-simple-login.js:92:407)
```

This problem only shows itself with IE10 on Windows Phone. If you need to reproduce the issue, you can use IE11 Desktop and emulate windows phone and ie10, or Google Canary, which has a device emulation feature.

If you think I left out important details or asked an unclear question, please do tell.

Thanks in advance

P.S. I wanted to contact Firebase support, but on the Contact us page they advice to use SO and put the firebase tag, so, here I am.

Comment: Trying to log into your app on the web shows a Facebook error, stating 'App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.' Have you properly enabled this app for Facebook login, configured Facebook login for Firebase, and taken the app out of sandbox mode?

Comment: The app is NOT out of sandbox (development)  mode. Would that be the problem? Firebase is properly configured with the app id and app secret, and I added campanelly.firebaseapp.com to the allowed sources of OAuth request to Firebase Simple Login

Comment: If the app is in sandbox mode, only the listed developers on the app will be able to log in with it. That might not be the entire problem, but folks here won't be able to help you debug it that is the case.

Comment: Hello, sorry I did not answer you sooner. The app is now out of sandbox mode, and it appears to work on IE10 on WP 8.1 but only if the browser identifies itself as a desktop and not a mobile device. In the latter case, the facebook popup correctly open up and close, but login is not successful, I can see that because the ui is not updated correctly.

Comment: If you're unable to make progress or continue to run into problems, don't hesitate to reach out to support @ firebase.com with steps to reproduce the issue and the expected vs actual behavior.